# Scala: create a dependent type variable from Any

Tags: scala, class, scala.js, dependent-type

I would like to create a variable with a dependent type.

I have

```
val a: Any = 5
```

and I would like to have

```
val b: [TypeOfA] = a
```

`TypeOfA` must be the subtype of `Any` (`Int`, `String` or `MyClass`) and not Any.
I cannot use scala reflection since this code is part of a scalajs code (which is not a the JVM).

What I have tried:

```
trait DepValue{
  type V
  val value: V
} 
def mk[T](x: T) = new DepValue{ 
  type V = T
  val value = x
}
```

But I don't get the result I want:

```
val x: Any = 5
magic(mk(x)) 
res70: Any = 5
```

I would like to have `res70: Int = 5`
It works well when the type is not `Any`:

```
val y = 5 
y: Int = 5
magic(mk(y)) 
res72: Int = 5
```

Is there any way do to that?

Comment: I think this is a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Assuming the compiler could somehow infer that type how would it help you? If you as a developer know the actual type of the value (or can somehow find out) - you can write a code that does explicit cast to that type. If you as a developer don't know the type, how the fact that compilers knows it helps you? You can't call any type-specific methods without _you_ knowing the type. In other words, you probably should describe to us your real, broader problem rather that this attempt to solve it.

Comment: I want to parse my class as JSON in order to return it as Dynamic to an angular-scalajs code. As there is no Writer[Any] and I need to know the type of the class in order to parse it, I need to know the type but at runtime, not compile time since I want a generic solution (so I cannot know the type in advance). So, I don't think that it is a XY-problem, if I would explain all the situation the question would have been too much specific.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting runtime and compile-time types mixed up. Your example is failing because when you say:

```
val x: Any = 5
magic(mk(x)) 
res70: Any = 5
```

You are *explicitly telling the compiler* that the type of `x` is `Any`, not `Int`. So it's doing what you're telling it to: at compile-time, all it knows is that this is an `Any`. (If you just said `val x = 5`, it would work.)

I think what you're asking for is that the compiler should somehow infer that the type of `x` is `Int`. But because you told it that it's `Any`, the compiler just plain doesn't know that any more at compile-time. The system only knows about that at runtime, which is much too late.

None of this really has much to do with dependent types per se -- it's more about the fact that you're hiding the type information, and the compiler can't just suss it out again...

Comment: Yes that's exactly this. The problem is that in the real word my val x comes from the argument of a function that is written in an extern library. So for you, there is no way to accomplish what I try to do?

Comment: Well, no *great* way.  I mean, the compiler isn't magic -- it can't just pull types out of thin air.  You *could* potentially write a big `match / case` statement, which would match on the actual runtime type, and have a separate call for each branch (since the branches will then have type information).  That's boilerplatey, and has limits, but I don't see anything better offhand -- with the type information lost, your hands are pretty tied...

Comment: Just to underscore why this is impossible to do generically: remember that `write()` is actually *writing code* to serialize the type to JSON.  (It's a macro.)  So in principle, to solve the generic `Any` case, it would have to write code to serialize *every type in the universe*.  On the JVM, you would fall back to a reflection-based serializer instead, but that sort of reflection doesn't exist in the JavaScript world...